# Network related information about the file transfer program

Tags: java

I am relatively very new to java. I wanted one information.

I am using the following code to do file transfer between one location to another:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetLocation);

// Copy the bits from instream to outstream
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
    out.write(buf, 0, len);
}
in.close();
out.close();
```

I wanted to know, what channel it is using for transfer, and any other network related information for the program?

Comment: you mean by socket?? it could be UDP or TCP

Comment: For files TCP is better because UDP is not reliable to transmit packets.

Comment: Your program (the code posted) is not utilising a network. If you are interested in [FileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) information, you can call [`FileOutputStream.getChannel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#getChannel()).